# PostgreSQL upgrade to version 12 - alter table without oids too slow

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade to PostgreSQL version 12 but it does not allow OIDs.  Removing the OIDs is doable with `alter table {name} set without oids;`, but for large tables this is taking several hours per table and locks the table.

I have a few ideas but both have problems:

- Dump to text, remove all commands to add OIDs.  The text file would be massive, not sure that's practical.
- Set a read replica without OIDs, then promote it.  I don't think such a thing is possible, but sounds great.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this with minimal downtime?

Thanks!

Comment: Logical replication (if you are on v10 or v11). Otherwise, Slony.

Comment: Try dumping it with `pg_dump` from v12.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, I will give those ideas a try and respond with results!